# Is it possible to verify using the hash of the file instead of the whole file, using OpenSSL dgst?

Tags: openssl, parameter

To verify a ***files*** digital signature, **OpenSSL dgst** takes:

- public key (from sender)
- signature (from sender)
- the file (to verify it hasn't been modified from original sender's)

[Example:](http://davidederosa.com/basic-blockchain-programming/elliptic-curve-digital-signatures/)

> openssl dgst -sha256 -verify publicKey.pem -signature senderSig.der
>   wholeFile.txt

**It** **recalculates the SHA256 of the file** and then compares that to the encrypted digital signature hash, to verify.

However, would like to do the SHA256 "myself" or outside of `dgst` and pass that value to it ***instead of the file***.

Something Like:

> openssl dgst -verify publicKey.pem -signature senderSig.der
>   **-theFiles256Hash SHA256ofWholeFile.txt**

Looking at the [command parameters](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Manual:Dgst(1)), seems possible but can't find the right combo.

Is this possible ?

If  `dgst` cannot do this, can it be broken down into steps using other OpenSSL utilities?

(Using ECDSA)

Comment: Should you not get your answer here then you could try your luck at [security.se] or [su].

Comment: `pkeyutl -verify` (and `-sign` to sign)

Comment: @dave-thompson-085: I am looking at pkeyutil, getting close, please expand on this as an answer if possible. . Noticed their "Verify the signature" example uses a private key..shouldn't it be the public?  http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/341356/any-insight-as-to-why-this-digital-signature-check-is-failing-using-pkeyutl

Comment: I didn't get notified, probably because you used - not _ in your @. Anyway, `pkeyutl -verify/-encrypt` only uses the publickey, but can obtain it from a privatekey file, publickey (SPKI) file, OR certificate file; for the latter two you must specify `-pubin -certin` respectively. (Whose doc I notice is a bit confusing.) This differs from `dgst -sign/verify` which takes only a privatekey file and publickey file respectively -- to verify using a cert, which is common, you must use `x509 -pubkey` to extract the pubkey to a separate file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>This does not answer OP's question since it is about ECDSA but people using RSA might find this helpful.</strike>

It is not possible to use `dgst` utility to verify hashes directly. One has to use `pkeyutl` utility:

```
openssl pkeyutl -in hash.bin -inkey pubkey.pem -pubin -verify -sigfile signature.bin -pkeyopt digest:sha256
```

Most of the parameters are documented directly at [OpenSSL](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/openssl-pkeyutl.html)

Comment: pkeyutl works for all supported algorithms: RSA for sign/verify/recover (including PSS) and encrypt/decrypt (including OAEP), DSA ECDSA for sign/verify, DH ECDH X25519 X448 for derive, as of 1.1.1.